# Create new pane from tmux command line

Tags: tmux

I have a script that starts a tmux server and creates five windows in a session. Then it joins all the panes into one Window to form a five-window tiled pane:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

tmux start-server

# create a session with five windows
tmux new-session -d -s MySession -n Shell1 -d "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'first shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"
tmux new-window -t MySession:1 -n Shell2 "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'second shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"
tmux new-window -t MySession:2 -n Shell3 "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'third shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"
tmux new-window -t MySession:3 -n Shell4 "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'fourth shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"
tmux new-window -t MySession:4 -n Shell5 "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'fifth shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"

# merge all panes in one window
tmux join-pane -t MySession:0 -s 1
tmux join-pane -t MySession:0 -s 2
tmux join-pane -t MySession:0 -s 3
tmux join-pane -t MySession:0 -s 4

# change layout to tiled
tmux select-layout -t MySession:0 tiled

tmux attach -tMySession
```

Is there a way to optimize it by directly creating five panes in first window (instead of first creating individual windows and then merge)?

---

**Solution**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

tmux start-server

# create a session with five panes
tmux new-session -d -s MySession -n Shell1 -d "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'first shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"
tmux split-window -t MySession:0 "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'second shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"
tmux split-window -t MySession:0 "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'third shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"
tmux split-window -t MySession:0 "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'fourth shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"
tmux split-window -t MySession:0 "/usr/bin/env sh -c \"echo 'fifth shell'\"; /usr/bin/env sh -i"

# change layout to tiled
tmux select-layout -t MySession:0 tiled

tmux attach -tMySession
```

Comment: Works perfect! I'd like to add: Every 4 splits you need to run "tmux select-layout -t MySession:0 tiled", otherwise the new panes will fail to be created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use split-window instead of new-window...